# Implementing operator< for x,y,z coordinate

Tags: c++, stl

I have this type which is basically a

```
struct { int x,y,z; }
```

that I want to use as a key for a stl map. Since it's a custom type, I need to implement the operator< for the map to do it's compare magic.

I'm having a hard time coming with the function that will allow that. So far, I've tried :

```
return X < v.X && Y < v.Y && Z < v.Z;
```

which is not working at all, and

```
return X*X+Y*Y+Z*Z < v.X*v.X+v.Y*v.Y+v.Z*v.Z;
```

which gives this shape instead of a square:

[image]

Keep in mind, the x,y or z value could be negative, which further invalidates the later solution.

Anyone have any idea how to implement such feature?

Comment: Well it depends what order you want to use... Is (0,-1,+1) bigger than (1,0,-1) according to you? There are many ways to compare 2 3-dimensional points, you need to specify which way you want to use...

Comment: How about `return X < v.X || Y < v.Y || Z < v.Z;`?

Comment: What does "less than" mean for your struct?  Ordering is important here.  If you just need to generate a key, then you basically need some kind of hash function for x, y, and z to use within your comparator.

Comment: @Gabe, you can't do that.  The operator cannot be ambiguous.

Comment: @Joe: In this case, the meaning of "less than" is irrelevant because the OP is just trying to define a total ordering. The problem with hashing is that he could get hash collisions, and then he's right back where he started.

Comment: What's actually needed here is a [strict weak ordering](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2010/02/order-i-say/).

Comment: @Gabe: not true.  A std::map requires a definitive order; this is because the underlying container is an ordered container.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I assume you just want any stable order so an ordered container will work.

```
if ( X != v.X ) return X < v.X;
if ( Y != v.Y ) return Y < v.Y;
return Z < v.Z;
```

What this does: you order based on X unless the X's are equal, if so you order on Y, etc.

Comment: also know as lexicographical ordering

Answer (score 7):

You don't **need** `operator<`, and you shouldn't implement it in cases where the semantics of the operator are not natural to all people working in the same domain to avoid confusion. Someone else might have a different interpretation of what *less* means, compare two points with the provided `operator<` and get confused with the result.

You are better off providing a comparison operator for your specific map:

```
struct compareXYZ : std::binary_function<Point,Point,bool> {
   bool operator()( Point const & l, Point const & r ) const {
      return l.x < r.x 
          || (l.x == r.x) && (l.y < r.y)
          || (l.x == r.x) && (l.y == r.y) && l.z < r.z;
   }
};
std::map< Point, Value, compareXYZ> theMap;     // uses XYZ comparison
```

This way it is clear for users of the map how points will be ordered in the container (say for linear iteration) and the lack of `operator<` will be less surprising than the presence of an operator that yields a *random* result.

Comment: `return l.x < r.x || l.y < r.y || l.z < r.z;` does not implement a strict weak ordering; i.e., this code would invoke UB if actually used with `std::map<>`.

Answer (score 1):

A 3-dimensional vector can be compared using the length of the vector

```
SquareRoot(X*X + Y*Y + Z*Z);
```

This allows for negative directions.

Comment: But if X is negative, it will be the same value. -2*-2 == 2*2

Comment: Cube them and cube root them, then.